# Combining scripts into 1 script using subroutines perl

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I'm trying to combine a couple of scripts into 1 script by initiating subroutines. The problem is that I'm having trouble directing my input from 1 subscript to another. This needs to be done for multiple scripts. These are the 1st 2 scripts from the whole list of them.

The data generated by code 1 needs to be submitted to code 2 and so on. but in code 2 there is an additional step of comparing the generated file with the original file.

```
Code 1: 
subst_head_1($infile);


sub subst_head_1
{
    ##this code helps organise the file in a way that it makes it more convenient for the file to be pushed into a hash for later analysis

    ##opening file
    my $i = $_[0];

    open(IN, "<$i") || die "\n Error: Cannot open the infile: $infile\n";
   # open(OUT, ">op.fa");

    ##giving all the headers in the original file line numbers
    my $lineno = 1;

    while(<IN>)
    {
    chomp;
    if ($_ =~ />/)
    {

        $_ = $lineno++,"\t", $_ ,"\n";

        subst_head_2($_);

    }
    }

}
    ##file organised in the following format; eg., "2>CBB_deg7180000000601_1100_2101_3"

sub subst_head_2
{

    ##opening files with header information(result of head-subs-1) and the original sequence(submitted query file) file for further info
    my $i = $_[0];
    #print $i;
    my $i_1 = $_[1];


    ##pushing file(headerinfo.txt) with the header information into a hash
    open(IN, "<$i");
    my @file = <IN>;

    my $file2 = join('', @file);

    my %hash = split(/[\t\n]/, $file2);

    ##opening the original file with the sequence information into an array
    open(IN1, "<$i_1");
    my @fila = <IN1>;


    ##foreach of the sequnces in the sequence file
    foreach my $fila(@fila)
    {

    ##Substituting any "*" in the file, if any, especially at the end of some of sequnces which were present in the file

    $fila =~ s/\*//g;

    ##regex for matching with the header information in the file with all the query information

    if($fila =~ /^\>(\S+).*/)
    {

        ##putting info(eg., CBB_deg7180000000601_1100_2101_3) into a variable $user

        my $user = $1;

        foreach my $has(sort keys %hash)
        {

        ##regex for the values in the key-value relationship in the headerinfo file
        if($hash{$has} =~ /^\>(\S+).*/)
        {

            ##putting info(eg., CBB_deg7180000000601_1100_2101_3) into a variable $user1
            my $user1 = $1;

            ##is the info the same?; if it is, then substitute it in the original with key from headerinfo.txt

            if($user eq $user1)
            {

            ##substitute header in the original file with the unique number;

            $fila =~ s/^\>(\S+).*\n/>$has\n/;

            }
        }
        }
    }
    }

    print @fila;
}
```

Comment: What about a global variable? Or passing the result from one sub to another?

Comment: Hi, that is the problem.. I'm not able to figure out how to pass the result from one sub to another.

Comment: have you tried anything along the lines of ```subst_head_2(subst_head_1(file))```

Comment: @tomc `subst_head_1` returns the return value of the last successful operation, which would be the assignment inside the `while` loop, on the last iteration step. With the code as it is now (if we disregard the function call), that's just one thing (see my answer). `subst_head_2` takes two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

My answer will explain the most immediate problem I see with your code.

Instead of this line

> ```
> $_ = $lineno++,"\t", $_ ,"\n";
> ```

you probably had this before you changed your program.

```
print $lineno++,"\t", $_ ,"\n";
```

All you did was change that to an assignment to put all of this into `$_`. But that variable is a *scalar*. That means it's a single value. It cannot take a list. Your assignment will put the first thing on the right hand side of the `=` into `$_`. That's the result of `$lineno++`, which is `$lineno` (`$var++` increments but returns the old value). All the rest is discarded.

So now your call `subst_head_2($_)` only has the line number. But in the subroutine you are expecting two arguments.

```
my $i = $_[0];
my $i_1 = $_[1];
```

The second one, `$i_1` (which is a **horrible name** for a variable) is `undef`, so you cannot use it as a file name to open a file.

But unfortunately your description is lacking a lot of information, so I cannot tell you what you actually need to do. Please supply sample input data and output data, and think about what you want your code to do.